# SkyDrive bookmarklet

Tags: onedrive

I have a SkyDrive account with lots of folders and subfolders.

Is there any script/extension that would help me to save images directly to SkyDrive?

When we right-click on any image on any web page, there should be a context menu option like "Save to SkyDrive" and then it should first ask me to login (one time activity) and then show me the list of root folders on my SkyDrive account where I can expand and navigate to the desired subfolder and then save the image to that folder.

Comment: Have you tried the [desktop Skydrive app as show here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/skydrive/download)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a bookmarklet, but you can try **[SDExplorer](http://cloudstorageexplorer.com/)** if you are using Windows. It's an extension for Windows Explorer (adds a directory that links directly to your SkyDrive account), allowing you to save images files from your browser to your SkyDrive account.

It should also be able to do what you described (ask to login, show list of root folders, and then navigate to desired folder).

[image]

[See more screenshots here.](http://cloudstorageexplorer.com/screenshots.php)